# Replaceitemvalue & date field & lotusscript

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I am using following code to create a new notes datetime item on the document.

```
Call doc.replaceitemvalue("dttimefield", format(cdat("11/11/2011"),"d/mm/yyyy"));
```

It does the work but when I open the document and see the documemnt properties it shows me as text list and having value as "11/11/2011"

Please help me what is wrong here. I want that as date time field not text list.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a NotesDateTime variable with the expected date and then use that variable as input to the replaceItemValue method.

Comment: even though I did like this dim dttime as notesdatetime, set datetime = new notesdatetime("11/11/2011") call doc.replaceitemvalue(format(cdat(datetime.datonly, "m/dd/yyyy") it does the same and put item as text list.

Comment: You are storing text when you use format (since it returns a string) so do this: doc.replaceitemvalue("dttimefield", dttime)

Comment: But how to achive the format then I want to store the value as "m/dd/yyyy" format only.

Comment: You need to store the item as a dateTime object. Formatting is not related to storing the value. You can control formatting in views and on forms.

Comment: even with this it stores text list not date time, please assist

Comment: If you want further assistance, revise your question to show your exact current code.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Is it error with ";" or it's Java?

I try with your code and it's get a date/time type.

Comment: No it is LS only and I dont get any error and I dont have semi colon as well. it just simply puts text list in the docuemnt once it is saved.